# Child process cannot write to the file?

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("stories.txt", "w");


  if (!f) {
    error("Can't open stories.txt");
  }

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1) {
    error("Can't fork process");
  }

  if (!pid) {     

    fprintf(f, "f---- child process wrote\n");

    printf("---- child process wrote\n");

    if (execl("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", NULL) == -1) {
        error("Can't run script");
    }

  }

  fprintf(stdout, "parent process wrote it after fork!\n");
  fprintf(f, "parent process wrote it before return main!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code in Ubuntu Linux 64-bit, this

```
        fprintf(f, "f---- child process wrote\n");
```

is not written in the `stories.txt` file.

Can you help me explain why this happens?

When I comment out the `execl` then the write to the file from the child process is done OK.

Comment: Seems that execl takes over the std descriptors so child process cannot use them anymore.

Comment: Yes, but I use fprintf BEFORE execl

Comment: `fprintf` is buffered, and you are closing file with low-level `close()` (actually, done by operating system on `execl()`), so that buffer is lost. Try to call `fclose(f)` BEFORE execl.

Answer (score 1):

use `fclose(f);` before run `execl`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("stories.txt", "w");


  if (!f) {
    error("Can't open stories.txt");
  }

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1) {
    error("Can't fork process");
  }

  if (!pid) {     

    fprintf(f, "f---- child process wrote\n");

    printf("---- child process wrote\n");
    fclose(f);
//--^^^^^^^^^^--//
    if (execl("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", NULL) == -1) {
        error("Can't run script");
    }


    exit(0);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "parent process wrote it after fork!\n");
  fprintf(f, "parent process wrote it before return main!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fclose() function flushes the stream pointed to by stream
       (writing any buffered output data using fflush(3)) and closes the
       underlying file descriptor. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html